# Function takes too long to run (over 72 hours)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an errorless code, which works for 3 days of daily data. however I wish to use it for 6000 days. It has not stopped running (we are on hour 75) There are two if statements inside a function with which I change a value if it is below a maximum or minimum, which I thought would be the problem, however when I removed those, the code is still running for more than a day (and going).
The piece of the code I am showing is the piece from which I expect the long runtime comes. It can however also be earlier on in the code.

```
var unweighted = function(img){var uni = img.reduceRegions({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
collection: grid2,
scale:500}).map(function(feat){
  var id = ee.String(feat.get('system:index')).cat('-').cat(ee.String(img.get('system:index')));
  var date = ee.String(img.get('system:index'));
  var bandNames = img.bandNames().map(function(name){return ee.Number.parse(name)});
  var values = ee.Feature(feat).toDictionary(img.bandNames()).values();
  var array = ee.Array.cat([values, bandNames], 1);
  var min = array.reduce(ee.Reducer.min(2), [0], 1);
  var key = ee.String(min.get([0,1]).toInt());
  var minh = feat.get('min')
  var maxh = feat.get('max')
  if (key>maxh){var key = maxh}
  else if (minh>key){var key = minh}
  return ee.Feature(feat.setMulti(ee.Dictionary.fromLists(['Minimum','id'], [key, id])));
});
return uni; 
};
```

Preferably I would still have a minimum and maximum check. What would be even better is that every band under the minimum and over the maximum are removed for each image seperatly. However at the moment I mostly have to tackle the runtime. Can anyone see why it runs for so long, and what can I do to streamline it?

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0c8d0697e742888d6c1ba3be1170a397)

Comment: Your code exported for me in 28 seconds: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NB1LgbKv3l24Q7XF0Shlo0I9BB096jR1

Comment: That is because the link I provided is the 3 day version, I need to upgrade it to 6000 days, which can be done by changing the imported data lines (there are two, and the other code line is already there, just changed into a text part),

Comment: Without a clue for the computation time, at least you will have to make server-side IF statements on ee.Objects: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a82e9c57ebecc736894cb4e8d2a98d85

Comment: I removed them all togheter before, does not change much. The code runs for more then 10 days and then stops running without result (internal error)